# Laravel install echo and pusher js without NPM

Tags: laravel, echo, npm-install

I installed the laravel echo and pusher js in my local environment with the following command:
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js

However, I don't have NPM command in my shared hosting.
What files do I need to copy over in order to have echo and pusher installed?
I see a node_modules folder created in my main folder, would that be it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Laravel Mix, you can run `npm run production` to bundle all your javascript file in a single js file (`public/js/app.js` by default) and you'll only need to upload that file to your server.